# Merging 2 dataframes if different fields are equal

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have 2 dataframes that have some features in common but labeled differently.
I'd like to create another dataframe with columns from both dataframes.
The idea for the selection is that if

`col1_df1 == col1_df2 & col2_df1 == col2_df2`

then the row must be selected. I used this code but I don't know if it is working properly.

Can you help me?

```py
pd.merge(data2_single_route, 
         data,left_on=['nodeid','res_time_start_s','res_time_end_s'],
         right_on=['nodeid','ts_start','ts_end'],how='inner')
```

Imagine that in dataframe 1 I have this:

```
10:00, 11:00, 1 , 'a'      
11:00 , 13:00 , 2, 'b'.
```

In the dataframe 2 I have:

```
10:00 11:00 , 1 , '1500'  
11:00 , 12:00 , 2 , '6000'.
```

The output that i want is:

```
10:00 , 11:00 , 1 , 'a' , 1500
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. I think your code should display only the rows, where all the values from selected columns in data2_single_route equal those of data.

Comment: can you add a sample data and expected final dataframe please?

Comment: @anky_91 imagine that in dataframe 1 i have this :   1)10:00, 11:00, 1 , 'a'      2)11:00 , 13:00 , 2, 'b'.   In the dataframe 2 I have:    1)10:00 11:00 , 1 , '1500'    2)11:00 , 12:00 , 2 , '6000'.    The output that i want is:    10:00 , 11:00 , 1 , 'a' , 1500

Comment: @AndreaFresa unfortunately comments are not the correct place for posting data, please update the question to include the examples and expected output. For help refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @anky_91 modified

Comment: I think your solution working nice, there is some problem?

Comment: whats the output you are getting right now, it should be same as what you expected as @jezrael said your solution is correct